# Q: Android not accepting special characters on Toast/Dialog.

Tags: android, dialog, character, toast

Im inputing some special characters on my toast and dialog messages, and end up switching for a "?".
Ive tried to follow some questions here on stack but none end up working.
Check one example:

```
Toast.makeText(Emprestimo.this, "Insira o valor do empréstimo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The word above "empréstimo" on the Toast message is like empr?stimo

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the character encoding of your project/ide, i.e. make sure it's UTF-8.

Comment: My ide is set as UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the toast text as a string ressource in your `strings.xml`  file.

You can do this by adding this to your file:

```
<string name="examplestring">Insira o valor do empréstimo.</string>
```

Then just call the toast with:

```
Toast.makeText(Emprestimo.this, getResources().getString(R.string.examplestring), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

If you don't want Portuguese to be the default language you should get yourself informed about supporting different languages at the [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. just a 2 minor correction: `R.string.examplestring` and Its portuguese.